# Centrifugal force in an open system

Tags: centripetal-force, centrifugal-force

Do you need to be in contact with a surface for centrifugal force to apply in an open structure?

E.g. if a bird flew into a fairground ride that uses centrifugal force to pin people to a wall, would the bird be able to hover in the air without being affected if it was not in contact with  any surface?

Would the effect be different if it was a closed system. i.e. if it was an airtight container that was spinning, could the bird hover in the air without being impacted by centrifugal force?

[image: Fairground ride using centrifugal force to pin people to a wall]

Answer (score 1):

The centrifugal force is an artifact of the rotating coordinate system, so it affects everything that you want to describe using that rotating coordinate system. That includes the fairground ride, the people inside it, the bird, and even the distant stars if you wanted to describe them in that frame.

For describing the bird in the rotating coordinates, since the bird is moving in the rotating coordinates, it will be accelerated by the Coriolis force as well as the centrifugal force. The Coriolis force will actually be about twice as large as the centrifugal force and it will be pointed inward. This will allow the hovering bird to undergo uniform circular motion in the rotating reference frame (in the opposite direction of the rotation) without being pulled to the wall.

Comment: The bird is not subjected to apparent force but observers in rotating frame see so. A ball thrown straight from ground passing through rotating frame seen curved by observers in frame but ball actually pass straight.

Comment: @NeilLibertine I cannot tell if you are agreeing or disagreeing with me. And what is an “apparent force”? I know of “real forces” and “fictitious forces” which are sometimes called “inertial forces”.

Comment: Apparent is that which is not actual or real, which you called as fictitious.

Comment: @NeilLibertine Apparent, actual or real are adjectives requiring an explicit definition of what a force is to be meaningful.

Comment: @NeilLibertine then your comment is mistaken. The bird is indeed subjected to both fictitious forces (Coriolis and centrifugal) when described in the rotating reference frame. As you said the trajectory is “seen curved” in the rotating reference frame. That “seen curved” in the rotating frame requires the fictitious forces

Comment: @Dale On that foot, geocentric is correct view, because every observation of cosmos is described through it. What do you think of light bending near sun when sun is not the frame of observer.

Comment: @NeilLibertine there is no such thing as the “correct view”. Any view is as valid as any other. When you adopt a rotating view then everything is subject to the centrifugal and Coriolis forces, not just things in contact with a co-rotating object

Comment: @Dale You said same thing and dodge complimentory question. There is correct view  information is often mixed with noise or carrier, one has to separate it  just as actual and apparent forces. In moving frame, ground seems moving back, but ground is not in motion and only way to stop ground is step out. Actual force acts everywhere, and inertial force also needs energy

Comment: @NeilLibertine there is no one correct view. That is the whole point of the principles of relativity. Inertial forces do not require energy, and in non-inertial frames energy is often not conserved. Please stop commenting with false information. If you want your “complementary question” answered then please post it as an actual question. Comments are not for new questions

Comment: @Dale Non-inertial can be source, so conservative for system. While inertial notion is myth at atomic level where you can't pull losses. Look at Maxwell's speed distribution, there is no acceleration left after most probable speed. What's good in posting question when a random one turn off because it not suit their ideology or vision of what science must be. And this is not complimentary, it comes from line of arguments, not to be precise.

Comment: @NeilLibertine this has nothing to do with ideology. You are simply posting factually incorrect information. It is a nuisance. To have to respond to your mistaken information. Without including the centrifugal and Coriolis forces the motion of the bird/ball cannot be explained in the rotating reference frame. That is a mathematical fact and your comments to the contrary are simply wrong.

Comment: @Dale Every observation is taken from the frame, there is no doubt. But relativity is all about observation of other frame.

Answer (score 0):

The feeling of an apparent force (centrifugal force) by the people on the ride is due to the fact that those people are undergoing *circular motion*. That is, they are moving in a circle, which means they are accelerating (the direction of their velocity is changing) and that acceleration requires a force (centripetal force provided by the back of their seat).

The bird, flying in the air, would not necessarily be undergoing any similar circular motion and so would not necessarily experience any similar feeling or force.

---

**Update:**

Apparently, there is some disagreement about this answer. So, I will explain further the question I think I am answering and the answer. To me, it seems like OP is asking about whether or not there is some kind of *intrinsic force field* within the entire carnival ride and therefore whether or not any object "within" the ride would be affected. My answer is "No." The reason the riders feel any effect is because they have been strapped into the ride, they have started spinning by virtue of holding on to the ride, and they feel an apparent force because they are undergoing circular motion.

In equations, if there are $N$ equally spaced riders on a merry-go-round spinning at angular frequency $\omega$, the position of the rider in seat $n$, where $n=0, 1, \ldots, N-1$ is:
$$
\vec r_{n} = R\cos(\omega t)\left(\hat x \cos(\frac{2\pi}{N}n) + \hat y \sin(\frac{2\pi}{N}n)\right)
+
R\sin(\omega t)\left(\hat y \cos(\frac{2\pi}{N}n) - \hat x \sin(\frac{2\pi}{N}n)\right)\;,
$$
where the radius of the ride is $R$ and the ride is assumed to be centered at the origin of these coordinates (and further assumed to not be tilted, like in OP's figure, but rather flat on the ground like a merry-go-round).

Next, suppose that a bird is flying directly along the $x$ axis in the $\hat x$ direction. And suppose the bird "swoops down" into the area of the ride.

A trajectory that describes the bird's flight path is:
$$
\vec r_{bird} = \hat x v_0 t + \hat z h_0 e^{-\beta t^2}\;,
$$
where $v_0$ is a constant, $h_0$ is a constant, and $\beta$ is a constant.

The parameters that describe the bird's motion are all arbitrary constants and have no correlation whatsoever to anything like $\omega$ or $R$, or any other parameter describing the motion of the merry-go-round.

**This is all that I am saying**.

In other words, the fact that the bird "swoops" down near the ride is irrelevant to any calculation of the *bird's* acceleration and there is no way that the parameters of the completely separate merry-go-round can have any effect on the bird.

Comment: They don't feel the centrifugal force but the push from the wall of the wheel. A bird that is hovering at rest in respect to ground will undergo circular motion relative to the rotating frame

Comment: The riders *feel* an apparent force that *seems* to be pushing their backs into the seat. This is the same force you feel on a merry-go-round and it *feels* like something is causing you to be pushed *away* from the center, hence cetri*fugal*. A bird flying over a merry-go-round does not feel anything different than it does flying over anything else. @nasu

Comment: That's what I think OP is asking about...

Comment: If not for the wall, they won't feel anything. Same as the bird doesn't feel anything. The pseudo- or inertial forces are not introduced to take into account feelings. Just to account for accelerated motion in non-inertial frames.

Comment: I don't see your point.

Comment: I'm saying a bird flying in the air doesn't care if the carnival ride is spinning or not, just the same way it doesn't care if Jupiter is spinning or not. Are you disagreeing with that?

Comment: To describe the motion in the non-inertial frame by using Newton's law you need the inertial force. No matter if it's birds or bees. Or persons. The persons are not more in the reference frame than are the birds or any other object. The reference frame is not a room that you are in or out.

Comment: What the bird cares about is not relevant.

Comment: Where do you see me writing that what the bird cares about is relevant?

Comment: See your previous comment.

Comment: You think that literally means "what the bird cares about is relevant"? I am saying that the bird does not feel any force due to the rotation of Jupiter in the same way it does not feel any force due to the rotation of a carnival ride.

Comment: And feelings are also not relevant. On the space station they don't feel the gravity of the Earth. It does not mean it is not acting on them.

Comment: And on the space station they don't care if a carnival ride is spinning or not. What is your point?

Comment: @hft you should pay attention to nasu’s comments. He is correct and is trying to teach you correct physics

Comment: @Dale No he is not. A bird flying along some arbitrary trajectory like (for example) $\vec r_{bird}(t) = \vec r_0 + \vec v_0 t$ doesn't behave any differently just because some other $N$ people are undergoing circular motion elsewhere.

Comment: @hft in the rotating coordinates the bird does behave differently.

Comment: I assure you the choice of coordinate system does not affect reality.

Comment: I have updated my answer to try and explain further what I am saying in my answer.

Comment: It looks like some confusion has occured due to people not being explicit about which reference frame they're using...

Comment: @hft thanks for the update. I think you are not answering the question asked, but at least your answer is not physically wrong. You should still pay attention to nasu who is correctly describing physics in non inertial coordinates. One thing in particular is nasu’s comment about feeling. You never feel fictitious forces. Here, what is felt by the riders is exclusively the centripetal force. Neither the bird nor the riders feel the centrifugal force although they are both accelerated by it in the rotating coordinates